# Deriving interest rate equation from the bond price?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

If a zero coupon bond price at time $t$, with maturity $~T~~~ (t<T)~$, is denoted by

$$B(t;T) = B(T;T) ~e^{-\int_{t}^{T} r(s) ds}$$

where $r(t)$ is a known interest rate.

How does this transform to $$r(T) = - \frac{1}{B(t;T)} \frac{\partial B(t;T)}{\partial T}$$

I know that $~B(T;T)=1~$ and we can rearrange, but I don't understand how to obtain partial differentials from integrals?

Comment: Try taking natural log both sides, then differentiate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$B(t,T) = B(T,T) ~e^{-\int_{t}^{T} r(s) ds}=e^{-\int_{t}^{T} r(s) ds}\Leftrightarrow$$

$$
-\log B(t,T)= \int_{t}^{T} r(s) ds \text{  } \text{  } \text{  }(1)
$$
Apply chain rule to LHS to find:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial T}(-\log B(t,T))=-\frac{1}{B(t,T)}B_T(t,T)$$
with $B_T(t,T) = \frac{\partial B(t;T)}{\partial T}$

By the Second Fundamental Theorem of Calculus RHS can be expressed as:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial T}\int_{t}^{T} r(s) ds=r(T)$$

Now Equation (1) can be expressed as
$$- \frac{1}{B(t,T)}  B_T(t,T) = r(T) $$
just as you wanted to show

Comment: Comments: 1: log is the natural log: $\ln$ 2: I have assumed that $r$ is deterministic.